# trying to get a list of images with a specific tag using the instagram api and node

Tags: node.js, instagram

Using the Instagram API i am calling the endpoint.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/MYTAG/media/recent?access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

I am getting different results returned when calling from my app vs calling from apigee.com. The difference being the access_token.

When i use https://apigee.com/console/instagram and make the instagram api call i get back 8 images. (after logging in with my instagram creditials), which is what i would expect.

if i log in with the same creditials using my nodejs app , i get a different auth token(which you would assume), but i get an empty data set back.

```
{ pagination: { next_min_id: 'STUFF', min_tag_id: 'STUFF' },
  meta: { code: 200 },
  data: [] 
}
```

I must be missing something simple. 
Can anyone see what i may be doing wrong in my nodejs code
Thanks for any help

This is the nodejs code:::

```
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var client_id = "CLIENT_ID";
var client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET";

var redirect_uri = 'https://MYDOMAIN/handleauth';
var authorize_link = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + '&response_type=code';

app.get('/authorize_user', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(authorize_link);
});

app.get('/handleauth', function (req, res) {
    res.send("ok");

    if (req.query['code']) {
        var request = require('request');
        var post_data = {
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
            'code': req.query['code']
        };
        var headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }

        var post_options = {
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            form: post_data
        };
        request(post_options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                var pbody = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log('Response: ' + pbody);
                console.log('pbody.access_token: ' + pbody.access_token);
                var options = {
                    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/MYTAG/media/recent?access_token='+pbody.access_token,
                    method: 'GET'
                };
                request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (error && response.statusCode != 200) {
                        console.error(error);
                    }else{
                        var jsonobjArr = JSON.parse(body);
                        console.log(jsonobjArr);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
});
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/ssl_certs/me.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/ssl_certs/me_bundle.crt")
};
https.createServer(options, app).listen(4000, function () {
    console.log("HTTPS Express Instagram server listening on port " + 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[You're in Sandbox Mode.](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/)

Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users.

I realized this because I could only receive data from the tags I've posted. 
Your question helped me figure out how to generate the access token. I couldn't get [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) to work. Thanks!

My suggestion is to build the best application you can to mitigate the approval process.